# SVGO: Killing #000000 fill

Tags: svg, gulp, gruntjs, svgo

I'm using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) and am running into an odd issue where it's killing my fill color, but only if it's `#000000`; or any variation of the sort, `black`, `#000`. I've tried setting `removeUselessStrokeAndFill` to `false` but it continues to remove that color only. Editing the src `.svg` file with something different maintains the fill color. Is there a setting I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're doing it right. There is actually an issue [#115](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/115) on the **[svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo)** about this.

To fix this, you have to set your color to another black, the closer to the real `black` is `#000001`. So you can change all your black color references to this in your *svg*, wait for a fix, or event better, install **[gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace)** and do something like this :

```
gulp.task('blackify', function () {
  return gulp.src('*.svg')
    .pipe(replace('#000000', '#000001'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks for referencing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, this is actually right behaviour of SVGO, because the default fill and stroke colour of an SVG is black and thus useless if it's redeclared as the fill. That's the reason it's removed from the output. Any other fill which is not the default, will be left alone as intended.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties